# Shouldn't this patent bear/state the name of the product or products (Prolon) it seeks to support/protect?

Tags: claims

In reference to the patent: [US9237761](https://www.google.com/patents/US9237761)

Answer (score 1):

No.

A name of a product is a trade mark matter, as it protects reputation. In contrast, a patent protects an invention. There is no overlap between these two types of IP.

In addition, a patent does not support or protect a product. It protects an invention (which might be implemented as a product, but need not be).